# How to run command radiobutton inside a container in a window?

Tags: c++, radio-button, command

How to run command radiobutton inside a container in a window?

I was looking for weeks on the internet but I do not think I conosco forums can help me with a library as sophisticated as windows.h. So I come to this forum for professional help.

I know how to create a radiobutton within the main program window. I also know how to create a radiobutton inside a container of radiobuttons, but I want to run the radiobutton command that is contained within the container.

It turns out that my program requires that when a radiobutton is selected style `WM_GRAYED` put an EDIT control.

The problem is not how to execute commands from a control contained in a container of controls within a main window.

My code:

```
hOptEnc = CreateWindowEx (
            0,
            "BUTTON",
            "Type input",
            WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_GROUPBOX,
            264,
            296
            100,
            64,
            hWndParent,
            (HMENU) CM_GROUPS,
            hInstance,
            NULL
            );

hRadioAssci = CreateWindowEx (
            0,
            "BUTTON",
            "Input Assci"
            WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILDWINDOW | BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON,
            10
            17
            75,
            20
            hOptEnc,
            (HMENU) CM_RADIOASSI,
            hInstance,
            NULL
            );

hRadioHex = CreateWindowEx (
            0,
            "BUTTON",
            "Hex Input"
            WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILDWINDOW | BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON,
            10
            37,
            75,
            20
            hOptEnc,
            (HMENU) CM_RADIOHEX,
            hInstance,
            NULL
            );
```

And each time the user dials an option as hex input, edit controls would change the coding. So I need the radiobutton run your command in the main window procedure function.

Answer (score 0):

The container (the group box) has no effect on the radio button. It is for visual clarity only. Pass you main window to the radio buttons as their parent window.

Comment: Thank you. I knew that, I have explained.

So what I can do to make the radiobuttons have a command (an action to be executed) when the user clicks on the radiobutton.

What I can do?

Greetings!